# WPF Datagrid CollectionViewSource usage when columns are reordered

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid

I am working on WPF `Datagrid` where we are customizing the grid to support functionalities like search, filter, column Hiding/Un-Hiding etc,

For Filter and Search we are using `CollectionViewSource` to get the `ICollectionView` and on that list we are performing various operations mentioned above.

For a particular Functionality like search, User had reordered the columns and then performed search operation, i am getting the `ICollectionView` data using the below function:

```
ICollectionView objDatacollectionview = 
    CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(DataSource.DataGridSrcCollection);
```

`DataSource.DataGridSrcCollection` is my `ObservableCollection<DataRowView>`.

From the `objDataCollectionView` object, I get the `itemArray` of each row and search for the text and start highlighting the cell where the text is found, but the problem I am facing is my `CollectionViewSource` object always returns the `DataRow` `ItemArray` in the original order when the Grid is loaded, as it is not considering the Column Reordering, the search is not pointing to the first column, it is actually pointing to the column which was the first column when loaded for the first match text.

The question I had is , is there a way to get the item array value in the correct order on how the columns are re-ordered, if not can I use any other approach with `Collectionview` so that I can highlight the correct item when search is done.

Below is the sample code i had

below is the sample code

```
objDatacollectionview = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(DataSource.DataGridSrcCollection)                                                                          
// Initially get all the DataRowview ItemArray , Here i get all the rows itemarray text as it is
    var temp = (from s in objDatacollectionview.OfType<DataRowView>()
                select s.Row.ItemArray).ToList();   

     for (int i = 0; i < temp.Count(); i++)
    {

   // Now in each item array , i search for the string and will get the list of the strings that match the searchText 
        var cellitems = temp[i].Where(x => x.ToString().Contains(searchText, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)).
            Select(x => x).ToList();

      //This is to point to the row where there is first occurance of the searched text.This will execute only for the first time
      if (cellitems.Count() != 0 && !IsfirstSelectedRowIndex)
      {
        DataRowView dv = objDatacollectionview.OfType<DataRowView>().ElementAt(i);

        objDatacollectionview.MoveCurrentTo(dv);

        int cellIndex = temp[i].Select((Value, Index) => new { Value, Index }).Single(p => p.Value.Equals(cellitems[0])).Index;
        DataGridCellInfo cellinfo = new DataGridCellInfo(cellitems[0], batchDataGrid.Columns[cellIndex]);
        batchDataGrid.CurrentCell = cellinfo;

        IsfirstSelectedRowIndex = true;
      } 
}  `
```

In the above code as i am moving through each row itemArray data i have is the original order, not the re-ordered columns, i can use the index to column mapping, but after this operation i have to support previous search item and next search item, so i am thinking that would impact the performance if i am doing search with column display index every time.

Comment: Can't you just index the item array by column name instead of index, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Each `DataGridColumn` has a `DisplayIndex` property, which will tell you the current position of the column. This will allow you to determine the ordering.

Comment: Hello Glen, i just edited by question by adding the sample code.